# Strings from CSV adding hidden characters, so when comparing, result is always false

Tags: php, string, csv, comparison

I am pulling data from a CSV and doing comparisons with it

```
private function isCsvValid($fileLocation){
    $file = fopen($fileLocation, 'r');
    $line1 = fgetcsv($file);
    $isValid = $this->checkCorrectColumns($line1);
}


private function checkCorrectColumns($line){
    $columnsFound = array();

    foreach ($line as $value) {
       //comparisons here
       if($value == "GBPAUD"){

       }
    }

}
```

However the CSV string has hidden characters in

```
    array(6) {
      [0]=> string(19) "363533840"
      [1]=> string(15) "GBPAUD"
      [2]=> string(47) "2007-12-02 17:00:33.000"
      [3]=> string(17) "2.326500"
      [4]=> string(17) "2.327400"
      [5]=> " string(5) "D
    }
```

Where as my string has to correct amount of characters.

```
string(6) "GBPAUD"
```

I can get the comparison to return true with this bit of regex which removes everything other than letters and numbers, which is great.

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9]/
```

But this will remove the .'s in a float and - in date etc

every bit of data has extra characters. Id rather not have to have a piece tailerd regex for each string.

Can anyone tell me how i get the strings to be the correct number of bits? Iv search all over the internet but none of the suggestions work (eg binary safe compparison, stripping html entaties etc...)

Is there anyway i can remove all hidden characters on all strings?

Comment: Putting your print_r($value) inside of a textarea , where your browser won't "interpret" content  might shed some light, as would a peek at a raw CSV line.

Comment: if by looking at the raw CSV you mean opening the file with head -1 (or opening in nano or vim or something), this is the first line 
363533823,GBP/AUD,2007-12-02 17:00:24.000,2.326400,2.327300,D

Comment: I thought it might be a format issue, so i tried converting the string to utf-8 but still no cigar

Comment: I found the answer
 $string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $value);

Comment: Instead of adding the answer at the bottom of your question you should add it as an actual answer to your question and select that as the accepted answer (you may need to wait 24h before you can accept your own answer). That will mark this question as answered and remove it from the unanswered questions list.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i did try but couldent see awnser question. but you are correct i had to wait 24 hours. thanks again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution, using this bit of regex

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $value);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just wondering how you figured the solution out.